# How can I view the contents of the Minimongo database in the client with Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I know I can query `CollectionName.find().fetch()` in the browser's JS console. Are there other tools that are the equivalent of a GUI admin tool for *all*  the browser's local minimongo storage ?

Comment: You may be interested in houston, have you heard of it ? https://github.com/gterrono/houston

Comment: Well, that's server-side, but due to mirroring, it's pretty good- thanks for the link.

Comment: can you to use robomongo http://robomongo.org/ , but it is not the same what you have on the client or server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mongol](https://github.com/msavin/Mongol) does this, FTW, thanks to Max Savin.

Comment: Yes this pluggin works well but Mongol bypass the insecure package and shows all entities so it's not a real `browser's local minimongo storage` view

Answer (score 10):

You can either use a server-side privileged admin solutions like [Houston](https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin) or any other MongoDB admin interface.

If you want to query data on the client for a quick inspection, you can use `console.table`:

```
console.table(Tasks.find().fetch())
```

Answer (score 3):

Also I noticed no one has mentioned it but there is also for chrome a 'Meteor DevTools' extension that you can add to chrome tools. Once your meteor project is running you can see in chrome tool a tab called 'Meteor' that will show you what MiniMongo has.

Answer (score 1):

There is a open source MongoDB management tool called [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org) — which is very efficient and useful.

Comment: Minimongo is a client-side implementation of MongoDB that runs completely in the user's browser - so Robomongo unfortunately won't work

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome atmosphere package [meteor toys](https://github.com/MeteorToys/meteor-devtools) that shows the subscribed data on minimongo. It also allows to add, edit or delete data on the go. very handy.

Also, meteor toys may not work with latest meteor update (1.6.1+). So, I found a light package that does the same called [constellation](https://github.com/JackAdams/constellation).

You can choose from anyone. It will surely help debugging on minimongo easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Chrome plugin [Meteor MiniMongo Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-minimongo-explorer/bpbalpgdnkieljogofnfjmgcnjcaiheg), it's very useful and show you every collections/documents you have currently on your MiniMongo

**Pro compared to Mongol**

You don't need to add any package to your meteor project to works

Answer (score 1):

Open the console and do it:

```
Meteor.connection._mongo_livedata_collections[collectionName].find().fetch()
```

My current Meteor's version is 1.8.1. I don't know it is possible to do the same on the older ones.

Comment: `collection` is the name of the collection on the mongo-server!